# TypeScript class prototype includes instance member

Tags: typescript, prototype

Below is my code snippet:

```
class Hello {
    abc = {
        a: 'l',
        b: 1,
    }
    k = (prop: keyof typeof Hello.prototype.abc) => {
        console.log(prop)
    }
}
```

And the code works fine in TypeScript official playground.

So my question is: `abc` is a instance member of class `Hello`, **Why can I access the `abc` property from `Hello.prototype`?**

Comment: I thought I knew the answer. But tried it as well and it feels like incorrect behavior. Good find @L_K. Might be worth mentioning to the dev team

Comment: @OzLodriguez I'll open a issue in the github :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that for `class X {...}`, The type of `X.prototype` is represented in TypeScript as `X`, the type of an instance of a class.  From the (outdated but still relevant for this question) [TypeScript Language Specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cfb0adeadf1f21b5f8201cb2c0765f3f4467633f/doc/spec.md#825-constructor-function-types):

> The type of the constructor function introduced by a class declaration is called the constructor function type. The constructor function type has the following members:
>
> ...[snip]...
>
> - A property named 'prototype', the type of which is an instantiation of the class type with type Any supplied as a type argument for each type parameter.

So TypeScript thinks that the type of `Hello.prototype` is `Hello`.  This is, of course, not true in general.  It's true for methods, but not for instance properties, as you have discovered.

I searched through the [issues in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) <strike>but didn't find anything mentioning this.  It might be worth opening a new issue suggesting that the type of a class prototype be widened to only include methods.</strike>

EDIT: Whoopsie, I guess there are [several](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11558) existing [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20922) about this, which were essentially declined suggestions because it would hurt more than it would help.

I know for a fact that doing so would mess up some stuff (currently an `x instanceof Class` check will narrow `x`'s type to `Class['prototype']`, which, if widened to only include methods, would break everyone's code everywhere), so I doubt that they'd take such a suggestion.  <strike>But it would be nice to have somewhere to point as official word on this issue.</strike>

Anyway, backing up to your problem... the runtime code is good, right?  And you want this to work:

```
new Hello().k("a");
```

and would like a compiler warning on

```
new Hello().k("oopsie"); // error
```

?  If so, then I'd suggest taking `prototype` out of the equation entirely and use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) instead on the instance type `Hello` instead:

```
class Hello {
    abc = {
        a: 'l',
        b: 1,
    }
    k = (prop: keyof Hello['abc']) => {
        console.log(prop)
    }
}
```

This now behaves as desired and is not exposing the weirdness around instance properties and class prototypes in TypeScript.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Assuming you created [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30516), I see @RyanCavanaugh had better luck than I did finding existing issues.  I've edit the above answer to include them.

Answer (score -1):

The `class` syntax is basically just sugar coating. JavaScript still utilizes prototypes under the hood for instance methods. So eventhough you are creating a scoped member inside of a class. `Hello` is a global object that contains `abc` and even `k` won't be on it's prototype chain.

There is a nice article about the information here https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-with-es6-4d224591a8b1

More insane yet, you can actually do this

```
class Hello {
    ...
}

 Hello.prototype.hiThere = 'oh Hello' 

 const test = new Hello()

 test.hiThere => oh Hello
```

Comment: I don't think `abc` is on `Hello.prototype`, because it's actually initialized in the constructor.

Comment: Good observation. Even if you add another class stating `Hello2.prototype` TypeScript type will still work as well. I am confused by this as to why it's working. Might even be a bug! Might be worth mentioning to The TS github project?